# Strange difference between eclipse / build versions in Activity lifecycles

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost, android-lifecycle

I have  **MainActivity** which extends **TabActivity** and holds two tabs represented by **Activity1** and **Activity2**

1.If I run this App on emulator or device from Eclipse **MainActivity->onCreate()** is invoked, it gives user selection of places through a **Dialog**. When user selects a place, Activities for tabs are created and currentTab is also set bringing **Activity1** to front and **PAUSING MainActivity** .

2.Whenever I hit HOME button or hit Back few times. I can see that **MainActivity** along with **Activity1** and **Activity2** are **PAUSED**.

3.When I go to Application/MyApp after latter, The state of Application is maintained and I can see that whatever Activities were running are brought back to the front by being **RESUMED**.

### This part works really well

However, if I export MyApp as release version.

If I follow 1 and 2 and then try to go to Applications/MyApp
I **ALWAYS** get **Dialog** for place selection, meaning that **MainActivity** is being created which in turn means that it was destroyed while I went to HOME.

- Why this is happening with build version but not while i Run it from
  Eclipse?

What is even more strange to me is that when I press BACK button while on **Dialog** screen i will get either **Activity1 or 2** from my previous launch of MyApp.
Which means that **Activity1 or 2** (Activity that was in front while presing **HOME**) was not destroyed.

- Can **MainActivity** (base for TabHost) be destroyed while it holds **Activity1 or 2** that is not destryed?

Hope I explained it well

### UPDATE 27.03.2012

Now thats funny :)
I build apk then upload it to server. Then on my galaxy 2.2 I type in url in a browser and download apk. After its finished downloading I install it.
When Install is finished I have two options **Open** and **Done** when I press **Open** I can replicate the issue described earlier.. but when I choose **Done** and later access it through Application menu it works ok! so this choice determines how app behaves later ? why? how? Im puzzled

Comment: I will add that device is SGalaxy 2.2; emulator is 2.2 / 2.3.3